# componente para selecionar fecha y JSpinner en una tabla cambia la informacion en las otras filas

Tags: netbeans, java-swing, java-8, jtable, component

Buen Dia
Necesito de su ayuda para solucionar dos problemas.
inserte un componente para seleccionar fecha en una columna de una tabla 
y un JSpinner tambien.
de la siguiente manera:

Tengo una libreria la cual me ayuda a usar el componente para usar las fechas llamada

**RSCalendar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-tengo una clase llamada tabla_spinner, la cual es la misma para el componente de las fechas

```
package clases;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author ANGELICA
 */
public class tabla_spinner extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer,TableCellEditor{
    JSpinner spinner=new JSpinner();
    Object valorActual;   
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        return spinner;//y retornamos el label
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
        (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        //si el datos es un objetc osea jlabel
        if (value instanceof JSpinner) {
            spinner=(JSpinner) value;//lo convertimos a JLabel 
            return spinner;//y retornamos el label
        }

        return spinner;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return spinner;
    }

}
```

-y con el siguiente codigo añado el JSpinner y el componente RSCalendar a las tablas

```
    TableColumn Tcolfechachooser=vencimiento_productos_tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);        

    Tcolfechachooser.setCellEditor(new tabla_fechachosser());
    Tcolfechachooser.setCellRenderer(new tabla_fechachosser());

    TableColumn Tcolspinner=vencimiento_productos_tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    Tcolspinner.setCellEditor(new tabla_spinner());  
    Tcolspinner.setCellRenderer(new tabla_spinner());

    modelo_vencimiento_productos=(DefaultTableModel) vencimiento_productos_tabla.getModel();
    Object nuevafila[]={"","","","",""};
    modelo_vencimiento_productos.addRow(nuevafila);
```

1. mi problema es que por ejemplo con el JSpinner selecciono un numero en una fila por ejemplo fila (1), y cuando selecciono otra fila por ejemplo fila (2), esta fila seleccionada (la 2) en la columna en la que esta el JSpinner se transfiere el numero de la anterior fila(1).
   exactamente ocurre con la celda en la cual esta el componente donde selecciono la fecha.Osea que en conclucion el codigo que estoy usando hara esto con todos los componentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. mi segundo problema es al tratar de obtener estos datos del JSpinner y el componente para selecionar las fechas. 
   con el siguiente codigo:

   String fecha=String.valueOf(modelo_vencimiento_productos.getValueAt(vencimiento_productos_tabla.getSelectedRow(),1));

   String dias=String.valueOf(modelo_vencimiento_productos.getValueAt(vencimiento_productos_tabla.getSelectedRow(),3));

lo que me recolecta es esto:

-para la fecha:

```
rojeru_san.componentes.RSDateChooser[,-192,-20,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777217,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=240,height=40]]
```

-para el numero del JSpinner

```
javax.swing.JSpinner[,-193,-20,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSpinnerUI$Handler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@2df0c8a,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Answer (score 1):

Revistando bien la clase tabla_spinner, modifico la respuesta:

```
public class tabla_spinner extends AbstractCellEditor implements 
             TableCellRenderer,TableCellEditor{

/*
  Yo crearía dos spinners, uno de edición y otro para consultar.
*/
JSpinner spinnerDeEdicion =new JSpinner();
JSpinner spinnerDeConsulta = new JSpinner();
/*
 Dado como creas el JSpinner sin parámetros es un spinner numérico.
*/

///    Object valorActual;   este campo lo quitamos ya que el valor lo vamos
///                          a recibir en cada método.  

/*
   En este método queremos retornar el JSpinner para que usuario pueda
   actualizar su valor. JTable lo va solicitar cuando estemos editando
   una celda. Pero a ese spinner necesitamos ponerle el valor que nos
   mande JTable en el parámetro value.
*/
@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

    spinnerDeEdicion.setValue(value); //aquí ponemos el valor actual
    return spinnerDeEdicion; //y retornamos el componente que usuario usará para editar
}


/* Aquí necesitamos devolver el componente que va mostrar el valor
   que nos mande el método, que sería el que contiene la celda seleccionada.
   O sea, queremos devolver el JSpinner con el valor que recibamos que 
   en teoría debería ser numérico.
*/
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
    (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
   spinnerDeConsulta.setValue(value);
   return spinnerDeConsulta;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return spinnerDeEdicion.getValue(); ///aquí retornas el valor del spinner con el que estaba editando el usuario.
}
}
```

Comment: hola, hice lo que me dijiste y lo que ocurre ahora, es que cuando doy click en en cualquier parte de la fila se pone en 0 el JSpinner. y el de la fecha vuelve a null. :/

Comment: cambié la respuesta, espero entiendas lo que comento y te funcione.

Comment: gracias Alberto, lo intente y me sacaba errores trate de solucionarlos y no funciono,pero me diste una idea muy buena, el usar dos JSpinner. lo que hice fue hacer otra clase solo para el renderer-> que seria el spinner de consulta y otra clase para el Editor -> el spiner de edicion. y en el spinner rederer tenia que retornar la fila y la columna. muchas gracias Alberto